# Pairing Google Glass with iBeacons to push glass cards (information) to device (glass)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, google-glass, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

Hey I'm a student working on a development project on a Google Glass Application that will allow users to obtain information about a restaurant/bar/etc via info cards that will push to an individual users' glass display. The technology we are trying to use are iBeacons (BLE technology) as QR codes (our first choice) have been banned by Google. We ordered a set of iBeacons, but have not found any information at all whether or not these will work with Google Glass. Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks, and apologize if I butchered any tech terminology!

Answer (score 4):

In order to make iBeacons work with any Android device, including Google Glass, you need three things:

1. A Bluetooth LE Chipset
2. Android Operating System Support for Bluetooth LE
3. An iBeacon API for Android

The good news is that Google Glass has (1), and I have built an Android library that supports (3).  The bad news is (2), because as of today Google Glass is based on Android 4.04 and Android support for Bluetooth LE starts with Android 4.3.

I'm sure Google will eventually make Glass run on a 4.3+ version of Android, then you will be able to do this.  I have no information on how long it will take before this will happen.

In the meantime, if you want to get started with the Android iBeacon Library on other Android devices, it is available here:  http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/android-ibeacon-service/

Answer (score 3):

Google Glass XE16 (based on kitkat) now supports BLE. You can now scan for BLE beacons (aka iBeacons) and display a LiveCard on you timeline. Please check the following example.
https://github.com/noelportugal/GlassBeacon

Answer (score 1):

Google Glass has received Android 4.4 update so it is now possible to use iBeacons.

**http://indoo.rs/indoo-rs-app-for-google-glasses-is-here/**

You can use Bluetooth LE beacons with Android (and iOS) - using [www.indoo.rs](http://www.indoo.rs) SDK. 
Disclaimer: I work at indoo.rs.